# How to upload file to asp .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am looking for a solution on how to send a file using a form to an asp application. I am writing in the asp .net framework MVC Razor.

My form:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Data", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { encrypte = "multipart/form-data"}))
        {
            <div class="form login-form">
                <label for="username" class="text-info">Wczytaj plik:</label>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
            </div>
            <div id="register-link" class="text-right">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Importuj" />
            </div>
            @ViewBag.Message
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

My controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult Data(HttpPostedFile file = null)
        {
            if(file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/Data"), Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                file.SaveAs(path);
                ViewBag.Message = "Succes";
            }

            return View("AdminDataView", students);
        }
```

Unfortunately, the above code does not work, am I doing something wrong with it, is there another option to upload the file to asp?

Comment: "The above code does not work" is there an error? Are you getting the success message? Did you try to debug?

Comment: I have no errors. So I debugged the code: I load the file and send the form, in the controller the object passed is empty and returns to the original view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a typo and i suggest you that use `ActionResult` instead of `ViewResult`.

[Defference between ActionResult & ViewResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743741)

the typo is: `new { enctype="multipart/form-data"})` not `new { encrypte = "multipart/form-data"})`

Sample Code:

**View**

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("UploadFile","Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { 
enctype="multipart/form-data"}))  
{  
    <div>  
        @Html.TextBox("file", "", new {  type= "file"}) <br />  
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />  
        @ViewBag.Message  
    </div>     
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]  
    publicActionResultUploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)  
    {  
        try  
        {  
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)  
            {  
                string _FileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);  
                string _path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles"), _FileName);  
                file.SaveAs(_path);  
            }  
            ViewBag.Message = "File Uploaded Successfully!!";  
            return View();  
        }  
        catch  
        {  
            ViewBag.Message = "File upload failed!!";  
            return View();  
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link this gives you better understanding.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60519052/7761461

Hope this will surely help you.